# Tailwind css `@apply` do not work inside a css module

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an issue in my project.

I am using `nx` and `react` and I setup tailwind to work across all my projects/libraries.

Everything works fine.

Inside a Library, I am writing like a `terms and services` page, with a lot of text and I would like to style this independently of the rest of the app.

I made a `styles.module.css`

```
header h3 {
  @apply leading-11 mb-6 text-center text-2xl md:mb-10;
}

header small {
  @apply text-gray-2 mb-6 block text-center text-xs leading-9 md:mb-10;
}
/* ... */
```

and I import it in my page

```
import './styles.module.css';

export const TermsEnUs = () => (
  <div>
    <header>
      <h3>blablabla Terms of Services</h3>
      <small>Effective: 1 October 2021</small>
      <p>
        blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
      </p>
    </header>
    <section>
      <h4>blablablablablablablablablablablabla</h4>
      <article>
    //....
```

I would like those style to only be applied to this component and do not pollute the rest of the app.

The problem is, tailwind/postcss do not compile this css file

[image]

how can I solve this ? how to make this styles only available on this page (so only header h3 inside this react component will have this styles) ?

Answer (score 1):

[create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

`styles.module.css`

```
.h3 {
  @apply leading-11 mb-6 text-center text-2xl md:mb-10;
}

.small {
  @apply text-gray-2 mb-6 block text-center text-xs leading-9 md:mb-10;
}
```

```
import style from './styles.module.css';

export const TermsEnUs = () => (
  <div>
    <header>
      <h3 className={style.h3}>blablabla Terms of Services</h3>
      <small className={style.small}>Effective: 1 October 2021</small>
      <p>
        blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
      </p>
    </header>
    <section>
      <h4>blablablablablablablablablablablabla</h4>
      <article>
    //....
```

Comment: this should work indeed. but it doesnt work in Nx within a library project. it does work on the app project

Comment: @apply is working now but the dark mode is not working